# Python - index out of range on large initialized list

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at Python and I'm getting a strange out of bounds error.

The idea is that I need a cache initialized using:

```
arr = [0]*1000000
```

then accessed in the same function by calling

```
def func (i) :
    k=1
    a = i
    arr = [0]*1000000
    while (i>1):    
        if arr[i] != 0:
            k = k + arr[i] - 1
            break
        if i%2 == 0:
            i = i/2
        else:
            i = 3*i + 1
        k += 1
    arr[a] = k
    return k
```

if the value i is over 1500 it gives me an out of bounds error. The cache, however, is supposed to be initialized to a million ints. Am I missing something?  Thanks

Comment: `k`, `a`, and `i` aren't mentioned explicitly before you loop.  Could you post some more code, such that it includes the initialization of those variables?

Comment: sorry, added a more complete code

Comment: eventually the array will be passed in as a param, but I initialized it in the function to eliminate any other causes for the error

Comment: The Collatz conjecture eh? Pre-initializing an array here is a waste of memory (and time). Is this a memoization attempt?

Comment: If you want the memoization to do any good, you need to keep the data between calls to the function.

Comment: yeah, I'm not pre-calculating, but instead storing the values as they are calculated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated now that the code is posted:

I don't seem to get any problems up to 1500.  I *do* get an IndexError for `func(1819)`, for which the i evolution begins

```
1819
5458
2729
```

and winds up at

```
851290
425645
1276936
[...]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but that's not a bug, that's simply a fact that it goes higher than you made room for.  You could use a dictionary instead of a list to avoid this problem.

--

To be clear, here's the sort of thing I had in mind:

```
def func_with_dict(i) :
    k=1
    a = i
    arr = {}
    while (i>1):    
        print i
        if i in arr:
            k = k + arr[i] - 1
            break
        if i%2 == 0:
            i = i/2
        else:
            i = 3*i + 1
        k += 1
        arr[a] = k
    return k
```

which produces

```
1819
5458
2729
8188
[...]
851290
425645
1276936
638468
319234
[...]
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
```

and a final answer of 162.  I don't think I'd use `arr` this way myself, though, but what I *would* do depends upon what you're trying to do.

Comment: `k` isn't exactly explicitly mentioned, either... and we're assuming that `i` is initialized to 2 or greater.

Comment: i will be in the range of 1 to 1000000

Comment: @HarrisonHe: only collatz sequences of `i = 2**k` are guaranteed to remain below `i`. `i = 3` for example, goes up to 16 before going back down to 1.

Comment: hmm how do you go about initializing a dictionary to a million values? I'm also not fully understanding the list structure

Comment: @HarrisonHe: You don't, you add the values as they come up.

Comment: I see, is the access time similar to that of any array?

Answer (score 3):

This function can grow arbitrarily before it eventually collapses.

You're probably just hitting some number that makes it grow faster than it collapses for a while. If you put in 1 more or one less than what you're passing in you probably won't hit the problem.

If you *really* want to cache the results, dicts are more appropriate than lists for sparse arrays in Python.